# Sorting by a field in child table

Tags: mysql, join, order-by, sorting

There are two tables: `contract` (with primary key `contractid`) and `contractupdate` (with field `contractid` referring to a contract).

`contractupdate` also has DATE field `startdate` and TINYINT field `day`.

I want the list of contract IDs ordered by the value of field `day` in the latest (having maximal `startdate`) contract update which refers to this contract.

MySQL.

Comment: Question: Is the `day` field in `contractupdate` the day value of `startdate`? In other words, does `DAY(startdate)` = `day` ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: No, no such equality

Comment: What does the `day` field represent, and what is the range of possible values ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: It is not relevant to my question what is `day`. Well, I'll answer your question: day: 1..28 is the day of month, in every month at every day with this number a payment should be made

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. Maybe I am just misinterpreting the question. I withdrew my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT B.contractid,B.startdate,B.day
FROM
    (SELECT MAX(startdate) startdate,contractid
    FROM contractupdate GROUP BY contractid) A
    INNER JOIN
    contractupdate B USING (contractid,startdate)
;
```

Comment: Before you accept it, please check to make sure the output is what you are looking for. Is the output correct ???

Comment: No, output is wrong. It should provide only one ID per contract

Comment: You want to see just the MAX(day) per contractid ???

Comment: No, I want to see the unique value `day` for the contract update with greatest `startdate` (having fixed a contract ID). And so for every contract ID.

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: `MAX(day)` is wrong in every setting. Well, I have asked this question in the hope that it can be calculated using joins. It seems not the case and I will manage to solve it with subqueries myself.

Comment: I am giving it one more try. I updated my answer again, Please have a look it. If it still does not work out, you can issue a chat session with me...

Comment: The output looks sensible. I will gaze at your code to decide whether it is correct